# Visual 2017 Update 15.7.4 - Dark Theme: How to change the color of the braces?

Tags: visual-studio, colors, braces

I just updated visual studio 2017 to the newest version (15.7.4) and in the dark theme, the braces are now black, so I can't see them.. I just had a look through the options / Fonts and Colors, but was not able to find the setting, where to change the color for the braces. Has anyone figured out how to do this?

thx

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the Color theme to Light (Tools->Options->Environment->General) and then back to Dark and the colors should become normal (I actually went through Light->Blue->Dark but that another step should not be necessary).

Comment: Tried this, but did not work. I re-installed VS and now it is working fine again. Thanks for your input @ixSci

Comment: @Immi, it strange because I had exactly the same issue and switching themes helped me.